# Test vectors for floating point unit

Tags: floating-point, verification

I have designed a 32-bit single precision floating point multiplier and also a separate add/subtract unit in Verilog.

I have a script in MATLAB that I wrote that generates a bunch of random floating point numbers and generates a test bench in Verilog.

I compared the results from the ncverilog simulation to those from MATLAB and verified that my multiplier works correctly and that my add/subtracter works correctly as well.

However, I want to know a list of test cases that stress test my floating point unit.  Is there such a list?  I know of some programs like Softfloat, but that tests a floating point of a computer, rather than being able to merge that with a verilog test bench.

I should also mention my unit doesn't support exceptions like overflow, underflow, and doesn't support denormalized values.  The rounding mode is round to nearest.

Thank you!

Comment: This looks promising: https://www.research.ibm.com/cgi-bin/haifa/test_suite_download.pl?first=elenag&second=webmaster

Comment: Yes it does, now comes the annoying part of parsing those files. Thank you.

Comment: When I worked on FPUs many years ago, I used the following paper to construct my own test vectors for initial coverage and found it useful in rooting out bugs: N. L. Schryer. A test of computer's floating-point arithmetic unit. Technical report 89, AT&T Bell Laboratories, 1981.

Comment: @Tim , does "Floating-Point Test Generator - FPgen" have 64 floating point test vectors ?

Comment: @Tim The test suite  in the link provided by you, do you have any idea if it is  covered by some licensing agreement? I visited the site but i cannot find any clear indication of what is their  license  scheme for using it. I need to be sure as i will be using it at my work( that is if it is open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim's answer was the best, the fpgen suite:
https://www.research.ibm.com/cgi-bin/haifa/test_suite_download.pl?first=elenag&second=webmaster

Comment: Parse it in a proper language and write out some Verilog... don't attempt to do the parse in Verilog :)

Comment: @MartinThompson, lol, yes I did the parsing in MATLAB.  Thank you for the heads up though.

Comment: @starbox,@Martin Thompson does "Floating-Point Test Generator - FPgen" have 64 floating point test vectors ?Also how do i parse it to get in 32 but binary values ?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw, did you visit the website to see? There is a lot of documentation available.

Comment: I did , but count find what I wanted

Comment: @starbox Any idea of  the licensing of  the test suite at the link you have provided? I visited the site but i don't see mention of license for the suite

Answer (score 1):

The canonical [published] set of test vectors for FP are those from Jerome Coonen's PhD thesis.  They are available (on *tape*!) from IEEE, but I suspect you can find them in a more convenient format with a little searching.

Comment: Found it, not easily translatable into something useful. I think parsing the IBM file referenced above will be easier.

Comment: @starbox Where did you find the above mentioned test vectors? If it is not much of a trouble could you please post the link?